# getting error while saving a data into database in django using .save() method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have created 2 models.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class categories(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class tasks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and have created the forms from these models.
the view.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from .forms import CategoriesForm,TaskForm
from .models import categories,tasks
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'user/home.html')

def signupuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'user/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm()})
    else:
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('currentcategories')
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'user/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'That username has already been taken. Please choose a new username'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'user/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'Passwords did not match'})

def loginuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'user/loginuser.html', {'form':AuthenticationForm()})
    else:
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is None:
            return render(request, 'user/loginuser.html', {'form':AuthenticationForm(), 'error':'Username and password did not match'})
        else:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('currentcategories')

@login_required
def logoutuser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        return redirect('home')

@login_required
def createcategories(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'user/createcategories.html', {'form':CategoriesForm()})
    else:
        try:
            form = CategoriesForm(request.POST)
            newcategory = form.save(commit=False)
            newcategory.user = request.user
            newcategory.save()

            return redirect('currentcategories')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'user/createcategories.html', {'form':CategoriesForm(), 'error':'Bad data passed in. Try again.'})
    
@login_required
def currentcategories(request):

    categ = categories.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'user/currentcategories.html', {'categories':categ})

@login_required
def viewcategory(request, categories_pk):
    categ = get_object_or_404(categories, pk=categories_pk, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CategoriesForm(instance=categories)
        return render(request, 'user/viewcategory.html', {'categories':categ, 'form':form})
    else:
        try:
            form = CategoriesForm(request.POST, instance=user)
            form.save()
            return redirect('currentcategories')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'user/viewcategory.html', {'categories':categ, 'form':form, 'error':'Bad info'})

@login_required
def deletecategories(request, categories_pk):
    categ = get_object_or_404(categories, pk=categories_pk, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        categ.delete()
        return redirect('currentcategories')

@login_required
def task(request,categories_pk):
    categ = get_object_or_404(categories, pk=categories_pk, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TaskForm(instance = tasks)
        return render(request, 'user/task.html', {'categories':categ, 'form':form})
    else:
        try:
            form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=tasks)
            form.save()
            return redirect('currentcategories')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'user/viewcategory.html', {'categories':categ, 'form':form, 'error':'Bad info'})

@login_required
def createtask(request, categories_pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'user/createtask.html', {'form':TaskForm()})
    else:
        try:
            form = TaskForm(request.POST)
            newtask = form.save(commit=False)
            newtask.user = request.user
            newtask.category_id = request.POST.get('categories_pk')
            newtask.save()
            return redirect('currenttask')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'user/createtask.html', {'form':TaskForm(), 'error':'Bad data passed in. Try again.'})
    
@login_required
def currenttask(request):

    tasks = task.objects.filter(categories=request.user.category)
    return render(request, 'user/currenttask.html', {'categories':categ})
```

i am getting error at newtask.save()

Error is:

IntegrityError at /categories/16/createtask/
null value in column "category_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10, low, asdfgh, null).
how to procede with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
category = models.ForeignKey(categories, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Don't forget to make migrations and migrate after you do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keyword argument passed to the view `categories_pk`:

```
@login_required
def createtask(request, categories_pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.category_id = categories_pk
            newtask = form.save()
            return redirect('currenttask')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()
    return render(request, 'user/createtask.html', {'form':TaskForm()})
```

> Note: Instead of passing `'error':'Bad data passed in. Try again.'`
> into the context use the forms errors. `form.field_name.errors`
> contains a fields errors and `form.non_field_errors` contain non-field
> errors.